# Facebook (OAuthException - #100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (first_name) on node type (AnonymousUser)

Tags: c#, android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I've been using Facebook login in my app for a while without any issues.  We did a big update to our website and now I keep getting this error from some users, and only in our Android cordova app

> (OAuthException - #100) (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (first_name) on node type (AnonymousUser)

I can't reproduce the error, tried many different things, with Facebook app installed or not, different users, different phones.

I'm using this code in C# to get the user

```
var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(accessToken);
fb.Version = "v2.8";
dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=first_name,last_name,id,email, gender");
```

But if I do this

```
dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=id");
```

Then it works and gives me an id, but I thought first_name and last_name were always available.

I can't see anything in our update that would break this and I can't figure how the token would be for a AnonymousUser.  How can you get such a token?

**Edit**
Here is the cordova login code

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(
    ["email"], // array of permissions
    function (response: any) { ... },
    function (response: any) { ... }
);
```

Comment: Well, this seems to be related to a new version of Facebook.  I now get a message "You've previously logged into CompuSport anonymously.  You can continue to log in with Facebook on the next screen." when I try to log in from the web

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem too, someone reported to facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173424853153369/

Answer (score 0):

A workaround until facebook fixes their bug is to add public_profile to the list of permissions asked

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(
    ["public_profile", "email"], // array of permissions
    function (response: any) { ... },
    function (response: any) { ... }
);
```